# Synonyms for "ease of use"? Preferably shorter

Tags: synonyms, writing

I'm currently copywriting a description for a facebook page. Unfortunately it imposes a limit on me of about 200 characters.

To get to the point, I'd need a synonym for "ease of use" that's a bit shorter to trim it down. (Also, I currently end two sentences with "use" and it's not pretty)

Comment: "easy" or "EZ"?  Without a little more of the sentence/phrase, it's hard to help you.

Comment: usability? Only really saves you the spaces...

Comment: Perhaps "usage"

Comment: Why trim "ease of use", of all things? You have a whopping 189 other characters to trim. If you absolutely don't want to trim them and "ease of use" is the only thing you can touch, then it's by definition the least important thing and you can drop it altogether. *Especially* if you are already repeating "use". At any rate, "usability" is too obvious a candidate for this to stay open in its current form. http://thesaurus.babylon.com/ease%20of%20use

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like *applicability* or *utility* will suit your needs.  (*Utility* saves you five characters, and I'm not sure you'll find a word much shorter.)  If you're simply trying to avoid the *use* portion of your phrase, you can try *ease of operation*, though that doesn't meet your preference of being shorter.

If you're looking for something more adjectival, I think *user-friendly* nicely sums up your sentiment (in fact, this could be extended to *user-friendliness*, though truthfully I think that sounds slightly forced and awkward).  However, if you're trying to avoid using anything remotely related to the word *use*, I would recommend something like *accessible* or *straightforward*.

Comment: Your suggestions don't really fill the OP's need to use less characters.

Comment: @KristinaLopez Actually, *utility* saves five characters.  That's probably as good as you'll get.  Also, the title of the question only says *preferably* shorter.

Comment: Probably...without resorting to indecipherable abbreviations. Lol!

Comment: I agree, but then I have "focus on reliability and usability." and I don't know if that sounds much better? Hard